# Lucene "contains" search on subset of index

Tags: lucene.net

I have an index with around 5 million documents that I am trying to do a "contains" search on.  I know how to accomplish this and I have explained the performance cost to the customer, but that is what they want.  As expected doing a "contains" search on the entire index is very slow, but sometimes I only want to search a very small subset of the index (say 100 documents or so).  I've done this by adding a Filter to the search that should limit the results correctly.  However I find that this search and the entire index search perform almost exactly the same.  Is there something I'm missing here?  It feels like this search is also searching the entire index.

Comment: what do you mean by "contains" search? a wildcard query?

Comment: A WildcardQuery with a leading and trailing asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a filter to the search will not limit the scope of the index.

You need to be more clear about what you need from your search, but I don't believe what you want is possible.

Is the subset of documents always the same? If so, maybe you can get clever with multiple indices. (e.g. search the smaller index and if there aren't enough hits, then search the larger index).

Comment: The subset of documents is variable.  I think ideally I would want to specify a query that first narrows the possible result set, then the second more expensive query would run on that.  Sounds like that is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SingleCharTokenAnalyzer](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_9_4g_RC1/src/contrib/Core/Analysis/Ext/Analysis.Ext.cs)

Comment: Interesting.  So this seems to index each character by itself.  Then running the search it does an AND on all the queries.  This should be fast because it's actually using the index instead of expanding the query?

Comment: @goalie7960 Best way is to try and see. I used it in the past to find a part of urls, and I was satisfied with the result.

Comment: I ran this on an index containing 5 million records.  It seems to perform well the less characters you search with.  I think it spends a lot of time doing the AND operation on all the queries it creates.

Comment: To optimize performance, you can also use different analyzers for different fields.

Comment: Yeah that is what I did.  Seems to be designed for very short fields.